# How do I set a NOT NULL constraint on Django charfield?

Tags: django

I'm struggling with how I can set a NOT NULL constraint on a charfield.

Currently, my model looks like this:

```
class Tutors(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254)
    birth_day = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return(self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name)
```

I want to make sure that last_name and first_name can't be saved to the database as NOT NULL. Docs are confusing me a bit lol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify `null` in your model class. `null=False` is default

[Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#null)

Comment: that's what confuses me. Wouldn't null=False mean you can't save data to the database unless there is data? That's why I didnt think I needed the option

Comment: @jarjarbinks99 `null` means `nullable` here. `null=False` means value `NULL` can't  be a valid value for this field

Comment: ok I understand now thanks. I added the options to my models file but I can't make migrations anymore, says changes not detected. Not sure what to do, Ill keep searching

Comment: @jarjarbinks99 As Neo Ko says, `null=false` is the default. This means that the the existing migration already sets `NOT NULL` on every column. By specifying `null=false` explicitly, you have not changed the schema since it is already set.

Answer (score 2):

`blank=False` will enforce that any form for this model cannot have a blank value for that field. To set `NOT NULL` on the underlying database column, also include `null=False`.

Comment: I changed it to - last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, blank=False) - do I need to rerun makemigration and migrate for changes to take effect?

Comment: @jarjarbinks99 Yes. Whenever you make changes to models you need to run `makemigrations` and `migrate`.

Comment: when I go to run makemigrations it tells me there are 'No Changes Detected', even thought I made the change in model.py and saved the file, any ideas?

Comment: I have a similar issue. With db.sqlite and PostgreSQL. If 'null=False' is the default it should raise an error as soon as I leave out the attribute in the .objects.create()-method, which it doesn't. What is happening?!

If I look at the database I'll have empty strings ("") in the columns stored. You usually get this behaviour setting 'default=""' at your attribute field which I didn't. Is this a bug?

Comment: @kerfuffle Please post a new question with an [mcve] illustrating your problem.